# Office365 read Inbox email in C#

Tags: outlook, office365

Geeting below error

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

```
ExchangeService oews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
            {
                Credentials = new WebCredentials("mohanb@cubicsp.onmicrosoft.com","******") //state your Exchange username,Exchange Password and Exchange Domain
            };
            oews.AutodiscoverUrl("mohanb@cubicsp.onmicrosoft.com");     //User Mailbox whose inbox is to be accessed.
            FindFoldersResults foundFolderResults = oews.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            MEWS.Folder exchangeExchangeAPIArchivedFolder = foundFolderResults.Folders.ToList().Find(
                f => f.DisplayName.Equals("SentItem", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

I made changed in code here using **https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx**
now i am getting this error

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

Additional information: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService();
            _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

            foreach (EmailMessage email in _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10))) {

                email.Load(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.TextBody));
                string recipients = "";

                foreach (EmailAddress emailAddress in email.CcRecipients)
                {
                    recipients += ";" + emailAddress.Address.ToString();
                }
                string internetMessageId = email.InternetMessageId;
                string fromAddress = email.From.Address;
                string recipient = recipients;
                string subject = email.Subject;

            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are yo sure "mohanb@cubicsp.sharepoint.com" is the address of a mailbox? Have you tried "mohanb@cubicsp.onmicrosoft.com"?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I wrongly pasted email address, but after changed still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an authentication issue.

You could add the following code:

```
service.PreAuthenticate = true;

service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("YouEmailAdress","Password");
```

This is complete code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            //ICredentials creds = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx.com");
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("YouEmailAdress","Password");
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            service.PreAuthenticate = true;
            service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, " YouEmailAdress");
            ItemView view = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, SetFilter(), view);

            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                if (item.Subject != null)
                {
                    list.Add(item.Subject.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add("test");
                }
                list.Add(item.DateTimeSent.ToString());
            }  
        }
        private static SearchFilter SetFilter()
        {
            List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
            searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
            searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, true));
            SearchFilter s = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilterCollection.ToArray());
            return s;
        }
        private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
         object sender,
         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
         System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
         System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
            if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;
            }

            // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
            if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
            {
                if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
                    {
                        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                           (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                        {
                            // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                            {
                                // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                                // so the method returns false.
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
                // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
                // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // In all other cases, return false.
                return false;
            }
        }
```

If you use the acount is not your acount ,  you need to make sure that we have required permissions for EWS Impersonation as per the article mentioned below:

[Configuring Exchange Impersonation (Exchange Web Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095.aspx)

[Using Exchange Impersonation (Exchange Web Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204088.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alina, I set impersonation rights manually for office365, now its works.

Answer (score 0):

401 means your credentials are wrong.

Comment: I cross verified credentials is correct, can you confirm me one thing is it necessary to install outlook in local desk, for this reference Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll, I already add reference using nuget package manager.

Comment: Can EWSEditor connect to that mailbox?

Comment: Now i able to access mail from office365 mailbox, i set impersonation rights manually for office365. it works for me.
thanks for your help and support.